# Disabling alerts and errors in Django File Uploader

Tags: javascript, python, django, file-upload

I'm using this plugin: `https://github.com/zmathew/django-ajax-upload-widget` and I'm wondering if there is any way of disabling alerts/notifications when upload fails without changing plugin code?

I want to use bootstrap notifications instead of this ugly default alert popups, but also I have to use Django Eggs so I can't change the plugin code/files.

In documentation I've seen that I can set plugin behaviour when upload success, but can't see anything about upload fail. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've noticed that when using `showMessage` function when initializing plugin it can override default behaviour of the plugin. Problem solved.